# Understanding trasnform applied to dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe

Why has `.transform` been used in the code below?

[Source](https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-importance-and-feature-selection-with-xgboost-in-python/)

```
thresholds = sort(model.feature_importances_)
for thresh in thresholds:
    # select features using threshold
    selection = SelectFromModel(model, threshold=thresh, prefit=True)
    select_X_train = selection.transform(X_train) ####What is this doing? 
    # train model
    selection_model = XGBClassifier()
    selection_model.fit(select_X_train, y_train)
    # eval model
    select_X_test = selection.transform(X_test)
    y_pred = selection_model.predict(select_X_test)
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. The object being used to transform the data is the sklearn [SelectFromModel](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html). Have you read through the documentation? What is your specific question after doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general with sklearn:

`fit()` is used for learning model parameters from training data

`transform()` uses the parameters learned from fit() method to generate transformed data set (without changing the learned parameters)

`fit_transform()` is combination of fit() and transform() on same data set

So in this example, the training data is being transformed by the `SelectFromModel` model before being trained by the `XGBClassifier` model. From the sklearn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html), `SelectFromModel` essentially keeps features at or above a threshold value, and discards the rest.